# rx.sentMessage(#selector(UIViewController.viewDidLoad)) is not firing

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, rx-swift, reactive-cocoa

I have an app using `RxSwift` following `MVVM`.

**ViewController**

```swift
import UIKit
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

final class ProfileViewController: BaseViewController<ProfileView> {

    var viewModel: Attachable<ProfileViewModel>!
    var bindings: ProfileViewModel.Bindings {

        let viewDidLoad = rx.sentMessage(#selector(UIViewController.viewDidLoad))
            .mapToVoid()
            .asDriverOnErrorJustComplete()

        let viewWillAppear = rx.sentMessage(#selector(UIViewController.viewWillAppear))
            .mapToVoid()
            .asDriverOnErrorJustComplete()

        let viewWillDisappear = rx.sentMessage(#selector(UIViewController.viewWillDisappear))
            .mapToVoid()
            .asDriverOnErrorJustComplete()

        let logout = navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.rx.tap
            .mapToVoid()
            .asDriverOnErrorJustComplete()

        return ProfileViewModel.Bindings(
            connectStore: viewWillAppear.asDriver(),
            disconnectStore: viewWillDisappear.asDriver(),
            fetchProfileByUserId: viewDidLoad.asDriver()
        )
    }

    private lazy var disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        configureView()
    }


    private func configureView() {
        navigationItem.title = "Your account"
    }
}

extension ProfileViewController: ViewModelAttaching {
    func bind(viewModel: ProfileViewModel) -> ProfileViewModel {

        return viewModel
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```swift
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa
import ReSwift

final class ProfileViewModel: ViewModelType {

    typealias Dependency = HasReduxStore & HasImagePicker

    lazy var userID: String = __user__.id

    let data = PublishSubject<ProfileHeaderViewModel>()
    let endSession = PublishSubject<Void>()

    private let dependency: Dependency

    struct Bindings {
        let connectStore: Driver<Void>
        let disconnectStore: Driver<Void>
        let fetchProfileByUserId: Driver<Void>
    }

    private lazy var disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    init(dependency: Dependency, bindings: Bindings) {
        self.dependency = dependency

        bindings.connectStore
            .asObservable()
            .map { self }
            .bind(onNext: dependency.store.subscribe)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        bindings.disconnectStore
            .asObservable()
            .map { self }
            .bind(onNext: dependency.store.unsubscribe)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        bindings.fetchProfileByUserId
            .asObservable()
            .bind(onNext: dispatchFetchForProfileById)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }

    private func dispatchFetchForProfileById() {
        dependency.store.dispatch(FetchProfileByUserId(payload: userID))
    }
}

extension ProfileViewModel: StoreSubscriber {
    func newState(state: AppState) {

    }
}
```

When my view is loaded I would expect `bindings.fetchProfileByUserId` to be invoked. However nothing is happening. I updated my binding to trigger on `viewWillAppear` instead and everything worked as expected.

I do not know why `viewDidLoad` is not working in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `.debug()` to your `viewDidLoad` chain, as well as a print() to `viewDidLoad` method to see what exactly happens, but by the looks of it, it seems you're setting up your bindings after `viewDidLoad` (in the `configureView` maybe?) has fired so you never get any additional events, this happens only once during the view controller creation and would explain why `viewDidAppear` works.

Comment: ah I see, so my view controller is within a `UITabBarController` which I believe calls `viewDidLoad` when it sets itself up, which occurs prior to my bindings being configured. Thank you that was very helpful.